Calendar Table in Power BI
I've been reusing calendar tables in various formats for a few years now. I'd like to know best practices and if there are ways to improve them. Any suggestions for style, code, etc. are all welcome. Our financial year starts on 01-July which is why I'm adding 6 months in the financial columns.
Here's what I like:

TSQL table is can be reused more broadly in multiple reporting tools.
DAX table doesn't need to load on Power BI import mode and is very fast. It's a rolling calendar based off of a today's date variable.

Calendar in T-SQL
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Calendar]
(
    [Date]                       [DATETIME2](7) NOT NULL
   , [Calendar_Year_Period_End]   AS FORMAT([Date], 'yyyy12')
   , [Calendar_Year_Period_Start] AS FORMAT([Date], 'yyyy01')
   , [Calendar_Year_Period]       AS FORMAT([Date], 'yyyyMM')
   , [Calendar_Year_Quarter_Nbr]  AS DATEPART(QUARTER, [Date])
   , [Calendar_Year_Quarter]      AS FORMAT([Date], '\C\Yyyyy \Q') + CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER, [Date]) AS VARCHAR(1))
   , [Calendar_Year]              AS YEAR([Date])
   , [Day_Name_Short]             AS FORMAT([Date], 'ddd')
   , [Day_Name]                   AS FORMAT([Date], 'dddd')
   , [Day]                        AS DAY([Date])
   , [Fiscal_Year_Half]           AS FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, [Date]), '\F\Yyyyy \H') + CASE WHEN MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, [Date])) <= 6 THEN '1' ELSE '2' END 
   , [Fiscal_Year_Period_End]     AS FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, [Date]), 'yyyy12')
   , [Fiscal_Year_Period_Start]   AS FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, [Date]), 'yyyy01')
   , [Fiscal_Year_Period]         AS FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, [Date]), 'yyyyMM')
   , [Fiscal_Year_Quarter]        AS FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, [Date]), '\F\Yyyyy \Q') + CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER, DATEADD(MONTH, 6, [Date])) AS VARCHAR(1))
   , [Fiscal_Year_Quarter_Nbr]    AS DATEPART(QUARTER, DATEADD(MONTH, 6, [Date]))
   , [Fiscal_Year]                AS YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, [Date]))
   , [Is_Current_Year]            AS CASE WHEN YEAR([Date]) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   , [Is_Current_FY]              AS CASE WHEN YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, [Date])) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   , [Is_Future]                  AS CASE WHEN [Date] > GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   , [Month_End]                  AS EOMONTH([Date])
   , [Month_Start]                AS DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([Date]), MONTH([DATE]), 1)
   , [Week_Ending]                AS DATEADD(DAY, 7-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Date])), [Date]) 
   , [Month_Name_Short]           AS FORMAT([Date], 'MMM')
   , [Month_Name]                 AS FORMAT([Date], 'MMMM')
   , [Month]                      AS MONTH([Date])
   , [Week_Starting]              AS DATEADD(DAY, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Date])-1), [Date]) 
   , [Week_of_Month]              AS DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 7, [Date]), 0)) / 7 * 7, DATEADD(DAY, -1, [Date])) + 1
   , [Week_of_Year]               AS DATEPART(WEEK, [Date])
   , CONSTRAINT [PK_Calendar] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Date] ASC)
)
ON [PRIMARY];
GO

Calendar in M
let
    //Set the following variables
    Culture = "English (United States)", //Select a culture.

    //Figure the Start and End Dates, based on above variables
    CurrentDate = DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()),
    CurrentYear = Date.Year(CurrentDate),
    PreviousYear = Date.Year(CurrentDate) - 2,
    StartDate = if CurrentDate < #date(PreviousYear, 7, 1 ) then #date(PreviousYear - 1, 7, 1 ) else #date(PreviousYear, 7, 1 ),
    EndDate = if CurrentDate > #date(CurrentYear, 6, 30 ) then #date(CurrentYear + 1, 6, 30 ) else #date(CurrentYear, 6, 30 ),
    DayCount = Duration.Days(Duration.From(EndDate - StartDate)) + 1,

    //Get complete list of dates, Convert to a table, update name and data type
    AllDates = List.Dates(StartDate, DayCount, #duration(1,0,0,0)),
    TableFromList = Table.FromList(AllDates, Splitter.SplitByNothing()),
    ChangedType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(TableFromList,{{"Column1", type date}}),
    RenamedColumns = Table.RenameColumns(ChangedType, {{"Column1", "Date"}}),

    //Add Fiscal Time Groups
    InsertFiscalYear = Table.AddColumn(RenamedColumns, "Fiscal Year", each Date.ToText(Date.AddMonths([Date], 6), "yyyy")),
    InsertNextFiscalYear = Table.AddColumn(InsertFiscalYear, "Next Fiscal Year", each Date.ToText(Date.AddMonths([Date], 18), "yyyy")),
    InsertPeriod = Table.AddColumn(InsertNextFiscalYear, "Period", each Date.ToText(Date.AddMonths([Date], 6), "yyyyMM")),
    InsertNextFYPeriod = Table.AddColumn(InsertPeriod, "Next FY Period", each Date.ToText(Date.AddMonths([Date], 18), "yyyyMM")),
    InsertPeriodFyStart = Table.AddColumn(InsertNextFYPeriod, "Fiscal Year Period Start", each Date.ToText(Date.AddMonths([Date], 6), "yyyy01")),
    InsertPeriodFyEnd = Table.AddColumn(InsertPeriodFyStart, "Fiscal Year Period End", each Date.ToText(Date.AddMonths([Date], 6), "yyyy12")),
    InsertFiscalYearQuarterOfYear = Table.AddColumn(InsertPeriodFyEnd, "Fiscal Year Quarter Nbr", each Date.QuarterOfYear(Date.AddMonths([Date], 6))),
    InsertNextFiscalYearQuarterOfYear = Table.AddColumn(InsertFiscalYearQuarterOfYear, "Next Fiscal Year Quarter Nbr", each Date.QuarterOfYear(Date.AddMonths([Date], 18))),
    InsertStartOfMonth = Table.AddColumn(InsertNextFiscalYearQuarterOfYear, "Start of Month", each Date.StartOfMonth([Date])),
    InsertNextFYStartOfMonth = Table.AddColumn(InsertStartOfMonth, "Next FY Start of Month", each Date.StartOfMonth(Date.AddMonths([Date], 12))),
    InsertWeekEnding = Table.AddColumn(InsertNextFYStartOfMonth, "Week Ending", each Date.EndOfWeek([Date])),
    InsertFYQtr = Table.AddColumn(InsertWeekEnding, "Fiscal Year Quarter", each "FY" & Text.Combine({Text.From([Fiscal Year]), Text.From([Fiscal Year Quarter Nbr], "en-AU")}, " Q"), type text),
    InsertNextFYQtr = Table.AddColumn(InsertFYQtr, "Next Fiscal Year Quarter", each "FY" & Text.Combine({[Next Fiscal Year], Text.From([Next Fiscal Year Quarter Nbr], "en-AU")}, " Q"), type text),
    InsertIsFuture = Table.AddColumn(InsertNextFYQtr, "Is Future", each if [Date] > CurrentDate then 1 else 0),
    InsertIsCurrentFY = Table.AddColumn(InsertIsFuture, "Is Current FY", each if [Fiscal Year] = Date.ToText(Date.AddMonths(CurrentDate, 6), "yyyy") then 1 else 0),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(InsertIsCurrentFY, each true),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Start of Month", type date}, {"Next FY Start of Month", type date}, {"Week Ending", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type"

Calendar in DAX
Calendar = 
VAR _today_date =        TODAY()  //'Properties'[Today Date]
VAR _fiscal_year =       YEAR(EDATE( _today_date, 6))
VAR _fiscal_year_start = DATE ( _fiscal_year - 1, 07, 01)
VAR _fiscal_year_end =   DATE ( _fiscal_year, 06, 30)

VAR _result = 
    ADDCOLUMNS
    (
        CALENDAR(_fiscal_year_start, _fiscal_year_end)
        , "Calendar Year Period End",   FORMAT([Date], "yyyy12")
        , "Calendar Year Period Start", FORMAT([Date], "yyyy01")
        , "Calendar Year Period",       FORMAT([Date], "yyyyMM")
        , "Calendar Year Quarter Nbr",  QUARTER([Date])
        , "Calendar Year Quarter",      FORMAT([Date], "\C\Yyyyy \Qq")
        , "Calendar Year",              YEAR([Date])
        , "Day Name Short",             FORMAT([Date], "DDD")
        , "Day Name",                   FORMAT([Date], "DDDD")
        , "Day",                        DAY([Date])
        , "Fiscal Year Period End",     FORMAT(EDATE([Date], 6), "yyyy12")
        , "Fiscal Year Period Start",   FORMAT(EDATE([Date], 6), "yyyy01")
        , "Fiscal Year Period",         FORMAT(EDATE([Date], 6), "yyyyMM")
        , "Fiscal Year Quarter Nbr",    FORMAT(EDATE([Date], 6), "q")
        , "Fiscal Year Quarter",        FORMAT(EDATE([Date], 6), "\F\Yyyyy \Qq")
        , "Fiscal Year Half",           FORMAT(EDATE([Date], 6), "\F\Yyyyy \H") & ROUNDUP(MONTH(EDATE([Date], 6)) / 6, 0)
        , "Fiscal Year",                YEAR(EDATE([Date], 6))
        , "Is Current FY",              IF(YEAR(EDATE([Date], 6)) = _fiscal_year, 1, 0)
        , "Is Future",                  IF([Date] > _today_date, 1, 0)
        , "Month End",                  EOMONTH([Date], 0)
        , "Month Name Short",           FORMAT([Date], "MMM")
        , "Month Name",                 FORMAT([Date], "MMMM")
        , "Month Start",                DATE(YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date]), 1)
        , "Month",                      MONTH([Date])
        , "Week Ending",                [Date] + 7 - WEEKDAY([Date], 1) // Saturday
        , "Week Starting",              [Date] - WEEKDAY([Date], 1) + 1 // Sunday
        , "Week of Month",              1 + WEEKNUM([Date]) - WEEKNUM( EOMONTH([Date], -1 ) + 1 )
        , "Week of Year",               WEEKNUM([Date])
    )

RETURN
_result

